# Linking java functions/subroutines

Tags: java, function

I am developing a slots machine game as part of an assignment.
I have two functions that I need to link together, shown below:

```
public static void DisplayOnScreen(){

    int LeftVal = GenerateNumber();
    int MidVal = GenerateNumber();
    int RightVal = GenerateNumber();


    FruitVal1 = showFruit[LeftVal];
    FruitVal2 = showFruit[MidVal];
    FruitVal3 = showFruit[RightVal];

    System.out.println("               |",FruitVal1, "|", FruitVal2, "|", FruitVal3, "|           ");
```

--

```
public String showFruit(int inVal) {

    String[] strFruitArr = new String[6];

    strFruitArr[0] = "Orange";
    strFruitArr[1] = "Pear";
    strFruitArr[2] = "Banana";
    strFruitArr[3] = "Cherry";
    strFruitArr[4] = "Lemon";
    strFruitArr[5] = "Apple";
    strFruitArr[6] = "Bar";

    while(inVal > 0){
        if(inVal == 0){
            return strFruitArr[0];
        }
        else if (inVal == 7){
            return strFruitArr[6];

            }
        else{
            return strFruitArr[inVal];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, each **"FruitVal"** is assigned by taking for example **"LeftVal"** which is a randomly generated number, and applying that to one of the fruits from the **"showFruit"** function. I'm aware this is done completely wrong however i do not understand the different java functions to do so.
**Could someone explain the basic java functions e.g. 'public static void' and try and help implement them in to this code correctly.**

If anyone wants to see the full program code then please do ask, I wasn't sure if the full code was necessary, however it is only short.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not where you come to learn a new programming language. We cannot explain basic Java functions. This you have to learn from your teacher, book, tutorial, etc. It's not a fit subject for a Question-and-answer site.

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions. Search "Java naming conventions" for details. There are many but all are based on the original Sun coding conventions document. The convention in a nutshell is that all names except package and constant names are in camel case, compound words with each compound part capitalized except maybe the first letter. Type names start with an upper-case letter. Method and non-constant variable names start with a lower-case letter. Package names are in all lower case. Constant names are in all upper case, with compound-word parts separated by underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Java coding standards.  Your code will be more readable.

You link them by having one method return the data that the other needs to have passed to it.

```
public void displayFruitOnScreen(String [] fruit) {
   // display here
}

public String [] getFruit() {
    // populate the fruit array here
}
```

Neither of these is static; they are associated with some instance of a Java class.